# Why does the code below loop on end?

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to sort the 3 pivot tables when the over/under slicer is selected. I have experimented with the under sort in the code below. It errors on the Pivottable(:MilesLoss") line.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Variance").SlicerItems("Over").Selected = True Then
    MsgBox "Over"
ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Variance").SlicerItems("Under").Selected = True Then

    Sheets("pdPIVOTS").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TaskLoss20").PivotFields("Name").AutoSort xlAscending _
        , "Sum of Work Variance", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TaskLoss20").PivotColumnAxis _
        .PivotLines(1), 1

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MileLoss20").PivotFields("Parent Milestone").AutoSort _
        xlAscending, "Sum of Work Variance", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MileLoss20"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1

            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TaskLoss20").PivotFields("Name").AutoSort xlAscending _
            , "Sum of Work Variance", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TaskLoss20").PivotColumnAxis _
            .PivotLines(1), 1

Worksheets("Project Dash").Activate
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If a sort is considered an update event for the table (I suspect it is), then consider disabling events (`Application.EnableEvents = False`) at the start of your code and reenabling them (`Application.EnableEvents = True`) only when you get to the end of your code.

Comment: AS @YowE3K said (with a suggested fix) You are triggering this code when the pivot table updates, and in the code you update the pivot table triggering this code to run which triggers an update of the pivot table which triggers this code to run which triggers an update of the pivot table which triggers this code to run which... Also.. what error are you getting? You don't say.

Answer (score 0):

You can set to `True` the selected property to `Over`, if it loops, then finish.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Variance").SlicerItems("Over").Selected = True
```